# Simple Java client-Server : Client doent connect to server

Tags: java, client-server

I am implementing a client-server application . I am new to this . I tried following the article [A Simple Java TCP Server and TCP Client](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)

Actually i already have a client that works ( Not my code )

So i just need to write the server for it .

Also my server will be connected by only one client so i dont really see the need to support multiple clients .

As i see using `netstat -a` a listening  server is created but the client fails to connect to it . There is no error message given out either which is suprising . Its as if the call to connect is ignored . No exceptions are seen on the client .

**My Server Code ( Probably Faulty)**

```
private static void create_request_server(int requestport) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(requestport);
        requestsocket = s1.accept();
          // Do some stuff . But this accept never breaks. 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Correct Client**

```
try {
            fRequestSocket = new Socket("localhost", requestPort);
            fRequestWriter = new PrintWriter(fRequestSocket.getOutputStream());
            fRequestReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fRequestSocket.getInputStream()));


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            abort(" UnknownHostException", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            abort(" IOException", e);
        }
```

**FYI**

Both my client and server are on localhost

Is my server horribly incorrect ?

**EDIT( Close to answer)**

SO with the help of the valuable comments posted below i figured out what the problem is . 
The issue is between localhost & 127.0.0.1

So i did a `netstat -a`  and saw that a server is created as follows :

```
TCP [::]:56283 Sin-Host LISTENING
```

instead of

```
TCP 127.0.0.1:56283 Sin-Host LISTENING
```

Thus the client is unable to connect . Any ideas of how to make the server bind o 127.0.0.1

Any changes that can be made to `ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(requestport)` ?

Comment: @Th0rndike the client **is** requesting one, with the `new Socket("localhost", requestPort);` call. Javadoc: _Creates a stream socket and **connects it to the specified port number at the specified IP address**._

Comment: @BackSlash yes you are correct .. thats the call

Comment: @BackSlash Yes. Comment deleted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there is a problem with localhost and 127.0.0.1
Try the ip in your client maybe this works.

Just to see it easier than in the comments with this constructor you maybe can configure your server:

```
new ServerSocket(1234,10,InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
```

Comment: Be careful with real IP's as you might need to modify your router/modem to actually send the message to your network's internal address.

Comment: @Sorontur : I have a bunch this is the problem . Is there a way to create ther server on 127.0.0.1 . Some variation to the API new ServerSocket(requestport) to include hostname as well ?

Comment: @skiwi This server will not be exposed to outside router . This server-client communication is very ``localhost`` specific . Small part of a big picture :D

Comment: sure this is not a final solution, just to check if this is the problem. Then you have to think about how to get it to work with localhost since that has to work as well.

Comment: @rockstar: yes i had these problems lots of times, and i'm currently looking for the code where i at least solved it :) give me some minutes

Comment: @rockstar It was a comment on this answer that proposed to go outside of the localhost, that's why the warning is there.

Comment: @Sorontur see my edit . I think you are right . ! i just now need to fix this !

Comment: i've seen i used the host problem with rmi so it is not helping you. but try this constructor: new ServerSocket(3456,10,InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1")); in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your firewall?

Possibly your firewall is blocking the requests.
The way you set up a connection looks a lot like the way I do it. But it works fine here.

Comment: what do you mean by " it works fine here " ? did you try it ? Also any chance this blocking can be seen in any logs . Will firewall logs have such a connection refusal ? I need to see .

Comment: What I mean is, the application I'm developing has about exactly the same methods of connecting. Blocking does not show up in logs because it just pauses the thread it's running on. Check your firewall to see if java has internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your socket, you still need to create an in and output stream to send and receive data from and to your server (lol grammar)

```
OutputStream writer = requestsocket.getOutputStream();
```

and

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestsocket.getInputStream());
```

Now whenever you want to send data to your client from your server you can do something like this:

```
writer.println("Data sending to client that's listening to my server");
```